# What the connection string after enable Azure Redis Geo-replication

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

After Geo-replication steup successful refer to this article, what's the connection string for the apps in mulitple regions.
For example,  I have redis-us(Primary), redis-eu(Seconday) linked on azure portal. and I have one app deployed in us, i definitely need to connect to redis-us(Primary) with connection string get from azure portal.

Then My question is, what's the connection string for the same app deployed in eu?
Does it required to use redis-us(Primary) connection string, to let app in eu negotiate with azure to detect which region of redis need to connect to. like, app in eu still need to leverage redis-us(Primary) connection string as well, and when the function need to write data, it will connect to redis-us(Primary), otherwise connect to redis-eu(Seconday) to read data, all this controlled by Azure Cosmos, the app is using redis-us(Primary) connection string all the time.

Does the flow like this? Can anyone confirm my question?

Comment: May you specify an article you are referencing in question?

Comment: @AndriyBilous this is the one i am referencing to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-geo-replication

Answer (score 0):

**Geo-replication is designed mainly for disaster recovery.**

Automatic failover across Azure regions isn't supported for geo-replicated caches.

It's recommended your primary and secondary caches exist in those same regions.

Individual application components should decide when to switch to their backups on their own.
If the application is in a different region than its cache, the added round-trip time would have a noticeable impact on performance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-high-availability#geo-replication

**Answering your questions:**

Connection string for redis-eu(Secondary) can be found in Azure Redis Cache, Access Keys settings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#access-keys

For app deployed in eu you can use redis-us(Primary) connection string for Writing, which is scenario for Geo-Replication. However you will get higher latency as application and Redis are located in different regions.

Azure Redis Cache does not have functionality to detect the region from which app is connecting